# Cloudera Hadoop Class file for org.apache.hadoop.classification.InterfaceAudience not found

Tags: compilation, hadoop, javac, cloudera, word-count

Here is the error I get when trying to compile this WordCount.java file.

```
$javac -classpath /usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-common-2.0.0-cdh4.0.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.0.0-cdh4.0.1.jar -d ~/wordcount /usr/lib/hadoop/wordcount_classes/WordCount.java
/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-common-2.0.0-cdh4.0.1.jar(org/apache/hadoop/fs/Path.class): 

warning: Cannot find annotation method 'value()' in type 'LimitedPrivate': class file for org.apache.hadoop.classification.InterfaceAudience not found
1 warning
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add [hadoop-annotations-2.0.0-cdh4.0.1.jar](https://repository.cloudera.com/content/groups/public/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-annotations/2.0.0-cdh4.0.1/hadoop-annotations-2.0.0-cdh4.0.1.jar) to the classpath

Comment: how exactly do you add this jar to the classpath? do i need to specify it in javac -cp .... ?

Comment: In the same way as the others are added (see question) : `javac -classpath hadoop-annotations-2.0.0-cdh4.0.1.jar:[other_jars]`

Answer (score 4):

Steps how I fixed this problem:

1. I created a directory called wordcount (`/home/cloudera/wordcount`).
2. Added `WordCount.java` to `/home/cloudera/wordcount` directory.
3. Inside the directory I ran the following command:

   ```
   javac \
   -cp /usr/lib/hadoop/\*:/usr/lib/hadoop/client-0.20/\*:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/\* \
   WordCount.java 
   -d /home/cloudera/wordcount/wordcount_classes
   ```

Answer (score 2):

For Hadoop version 2.6.0 you need to add the following jars:

javac -classpath $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.6.0.jar:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-annotations-2.6.0.jar:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.6.0.jar /path_to_your_java_file/WordCount.java

Answer (score 0):

A fast (but not advisable for production) in hadoop-2.6.x is

Unix/MacOS

```
$ javac -classpath .:$(mapred classpath):$CLASSPATH -d ~/wordcount /usr/lib/hadoop/wordcount_classes/WordCount.java
```

Answer (score 0):

Comment the below dependency from the pom if you have it

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-exec</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

And then enable hadoop-annotations